# Excel VBA: Elementary Row Loop Checking multiple rows, returning number in another row

Tags: excel, vba

First time in VBA.

Abstracted Problem pseudocode: I have an output sheet with 3 rows (date, code, cash).  I input a date in cell A1.

I want to loop through the date row and find the date that matches A1 input date.  If it matches I want to check the cell in the row under it for a "code" match ("code" is 1).  If both date and code match, I want a variable, cash, to store the value in the cell on the 3rd row of that matching column.  There will always only be 1 match, and 20 columns is sufficient to check.

I am getting an "object required" error on the "Set curCell" line.

****Changed the line to "xx".value2, set the 3 variables as ranges.  Still get the error?**

```
Sub GetCash()

Dim theDate As String: theDate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

Dim curCell As Range, perCell As Range, cashCell As Range, Counter As Integer, Cash As Integer

 For Counter = 1 To 20

 Set curCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, Counter).Value2
 Set perCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, Counter).Value2
 Set cashCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, Counter).Value2

 If curCell = theDate And perCell = 1 Then Cash = cashCell

 Next Counter

MsgBox Cash

End Sub
```

Comment: `curCell` is an integer but you're trying to give it a `Cells()` which is a range. Change that line to `curCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, Counter).Value2`

Comment: You don't need to `Set` an `Integer` - you should declare those cells as `Range`.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 ha I had deleted my comment, meaning to improve it. Yes the first argument of `Cells` is the row, and the 2nd is the column.

Comment: @BigBen dangit Ben I already cleared my comment :p

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 this is worse than phone tag.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for offering help! Much appreciated!  

I set curCell, perCell, cashCell to Range (leaving the "SET"), and changed all 3 lines to xxxxx.value2

But still doesn't work - runtime error...